# Typeorm returning. Connection string is being returned instead of data

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I'm doing this:

```
 async getPush() {
        const queryBuilder =  await  this.tableRepository
            .createQueryBuilder('table')
            .select('*')
            .orderBy(date,DESC)

       return queryBuilder  
    }
```

Instead of getting a json with my database data I'm receiving this string connection:

```
connection:
   Connection {
     migrations:
      [ InitialMigration1570479219390 {},
       ],
     subscribers: [],
     entityMetadatas: [ [EntityMetadata], [EntityMetadata], [EntityMetadata] ],
     name: 'default',
     options:
      options:
      { entities: [Array],
        migrations: [Array],
        keepConnectionAlive: true,
        type: 'mysql',
        host: 'localhost',
[..]
```

Why? Whats missing?

Comment: Add `.getMany()` after `.orderBy(date,DESC)` to get the data.

Comment: Have you try `.getMany()` ?

Comment: It works. Thanks